# Laravel login page redirects to verification page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm new in Laravel so please don't kill me for my question. I'm trying to make an email verification. I searched but can't find the right answer in my case.

**Controller**

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('verified');
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

The email verification works very well and sends me an email. My problem is after login, the website should take the user to the home page, but it takes the user to "/email/verify" page. Even if I try to write /home in the URL, it redirects to "/email/verify." I don't know what's wrong with my code.

**Routes**

```php
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only verified users may enter...
})->middleware('verified');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

// Admin Role route
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
```

Screenshot for the [email verification page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePHkQ.png).

Comment: You need to "verify" the email. Did you click on the link in your email while you were still logged in?

Comment: im using mailtrap.io  because i'm working on localhost so i can't verify the email.. do you prefer another way to use mail verification ??

Comment: What is the url you're using for your local development?

Comment: You can click on the link in mailtrap or use the log mail driver if you still have issues.

Comment: @RossWilson i changed this [link](http://localhost:8000/dozzun) to [link](dozzun.io)

Comment: @adam it worked but yesterday i doesn't work and i don't know why :)  
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

With what it indicates, it appears that you have not verified the email of the user with whom you have logged in.

If you want to avoid email verification in some controller method, simply do the same as you did with auth.

Try to do the following.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
    $this->middleware('verified', ['except' => ['index', 'show']);
}
```

Please, do not forget to mark the answer as valid if it has been helpful and give a positive vote.

A cordial greeting.

Comment: Thank you for your help .. it works in login but in register it doesn't redirect me to the verification page

Comment: you mean that when you register a user does not redirect you to home? If so, try to change "app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php" line `protected $redirectPath = '/';` to `protected $redirectPath = '/home';`

Comment: now when i login it redirect me to /home and when i register it redirects me to /home but i need when i login it supposed redirects me to /home and when i register it supposed to redirects me to verification page like the image i attached in my post

Comment: i found the solution .. the solution was i have to verify the emails but yesterday it doesn't work but when i tried it now it works .. thank you for your efforts ^_^

Comment: There is no need! But please mark the answer as accepted and add a positive vote if it has helped you. Thank you.